# link to c++ shared library generated by Matlab Compiler SDK

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, matlab-compiler

Tried to deploy **C++ code** integrated with C++ shared library generated by **Matlab compiler SDK**. Matlab compiler SDK generated a folder including `test.h, test.so, and readme.txt`

1. Install Matlab_runtime MCR 2.   Edit the library link path according to the readme.txt Open home directory and gedit ~/.bashrc file, add the environment variable XAPPLRESDIR & LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the file according to readme.txt 3.  Write the driver code main.cpp and Compile the main.cpp code use:

> g++
>   -L/home/yuan/Documents/Matlab2016b/Matlab_runtime/v91/extern/lib/glnxa64
>
> -L/home/yuan/Documents/Matlab2016b/Matlab_runtime/v91/bin/glnxa64
>
> -I/home/yuan/Documents/Matlab2016b/Matlab_runtime/v91/extern/include
>
> -L./test main.cpp -o main

and I got errors:

> /tmp/cc3Xemzh.o: In function main: main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined
>   reference to mclmcrInitialize_proxy
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to
>   mclInitializeApplication_860_proxy
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to testInitialize
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to mlfTest
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to testTerminate
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to
>   `mclTerminateApplication_proxy
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This should be the linking library problem, but I don't know how to fix this , anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to edit the library link path, [You must explicitly link against mclmcrrt.so](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/cxx/how-the-mclmcrrt-proxy-layer-handles-loading-of-libraries.html?searchHighlight=mclmcrrt&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).